# Jenkins - Execute Pipeline from Specific folder

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a main pipeline in jenkins that will checkout the code , compile, test and build, then push image to docker. This is the high level of CI pipeline that I have. Say job name "MainJobA"

I need to create a new job , just for JavaDoc generation. For that i have created a new script in Git Repo and configured the same in Pipeline job.

Now i need to execute this sub job of javadoc generation and publishing the html reports from the workspace of "MainJobA" . I need to run the SubJobA's pipeline stages from

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/MainJobA
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is `build` step exist in jenkins declarative pipelines.

Use it like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ("build") {
            steps {
                build 'Pipeline_B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```